# OSX: Get Processes open Files and Ports

Tags: objective-c, macos, process

If you open the activity monitor on OSX you are presented with a list of processes. From there you have the option to inspect a given process to view more information on that process. Doing do will open a dialog with a few different tabs of information. The specific tab of interest for my question is the "Open Files and Ports" tab.

My question is what interface is used to get this data. I've already figured out how to get a list of running processes using:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

and I know how to get some information such as the localized application name, bundle url, etc, but not how to get the open files information (I'm not too concerned with the ports information).

If anyone could point me towards the documentation for an API that will allow me to do this I would be most appreciative!

Comment: You could launch the lsof Unix command with NSTask to find this info.

Comment: ... or inspect the source code of lsof: http://people.freebsd.org/~abe/

Comment: And the source code for `lsof(1)` is available [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lsof/), if you're curious to see how it works under the hood.  But be warned, it's not pretty.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this approach. This looks like it could definitely have some promise. Thanks!